# Unable to figure out how toggle button is getting disabled

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Here I have this toggle button as seen in code below. A `control template` is also defined for this toggle button. At some scenario this button is getting disabled. ie I `cannot click` on the button anymore. I am following `MVVM` pattern. I have put break points and checked. There is nothing related to changing the buttons `IsEnabled` state.

Since the past 1 hour I am trying to figure out how the button’s enabled state is getting changed. There is nothing related to the button’s enabled state change or anything related to that in code behind too.
Hence I am not posting unwanted code behind/view model code here.

If you can help me figure out from the XAML code how the button state is getting changed to disabled, or which property is leading to that change, it will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="TestBtn"
                          Height="60"
                          Margin="5"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                          Command="{Binding StartStopResetCommand}"
                          Content="{Binding BtnState,
                                            Converter={StaticResource BtnTextConverter}}"
                          FontSize="16"
                          Foreground="White"
                          PreviewKeyDown="BtnPreviewKeyDown">
                <ToggleButton.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                    <Border x:Name="border"
                                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                            BorderThickness=".5"
                                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                          Focusable="False"
                                                          RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                    </Border>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                            <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="#595959" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BtnState}" Value="{x:Static my:ButtonState.Start}">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundBrush}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BtnState}" Value="{x:Static my:ButtonState.Stop}">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ExecutingStateColor}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BtnState}" Value="{x:Static my:ButtonState.Reset}">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundBrush}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ToggleButton.Style>
            </ToggleButton>
```

Comment: Button state can be changed automatically if your "StartStopResetCommand" implements "CanExecute" action and returns false at some point.

Comment: **Upvote.** So fast and precise. I never knew about such a thing yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button state can be changed automatically, disabled in this case, if your `StartStopResetCommand` implements `CanExecute` action and returns false at some point.

Also, if you want all controls to refresh their state depending on your `CanExecute`, you should call `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` on your command.

Comment: Thank you. Working perfectly.